# Using as.Date and grep to format inconsistent dates in one vector

Tags: r, regex, date, as.date

I'm fairly new to R, but I've had a great deal of challenge doing what otherwise seems like a simple task.

I have a number of inconsistently recorded dates in one vector. My goal is to convert them all to the same R accepted date format in a new vector labeled `clean_end_date`. Thus far, I have been able to use a combination of `as.Date` and `grep` to format almost all into the general `%Y-%m-%d` format in R:

```
d$clean_end_date[grep("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}", d$End_Date, value=F)] <- as.character(as.Date(grep("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}", d$End_Date, value=T, fixed = FALSE), format="%d/%m/%Y"))
```

However, there are several dates that won't convert regardless of how I manipulate the code. The rows that produce NAs use dashes instead of slashes as separators. Different date formats have the same number of characters, so counting them won’t help distinguish between them. I can either identify these rows manually, or use a regular expressions string matching function to identify the format. I thought `grep()` would help here, but it does not.

The code I have used to format most of it is here:

```
d$clean_end_date <- NA
d$clean_end_date[nchar(as.character(d$End_Date))<10] <- as.character(as.Date(d$End_Date[nchar(as.character(d$End_Date))<10], format="%m/%d/%y"))
d$clean_end_date[grep("[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}", d$End_Date, value=F)] <- as.character(as.Date(grep("[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}", d$End_Date, value=T, fixed = FALSE), format="%Y/%m/%d"))
d$clean_end_date[grep("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", d$End_Date, value=F)] <- as.character(as.Date(grep("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", d$End_Date, value=T, fixed = FALSE), format="%Y-%m-%d"))
d$clean_end_date[grep("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}", d$End_Date, value=F)] <- as.character(as.Date(grep("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}", d$End_Date, value=T, fixed = FALSE), format="%d/%m/%Y"))
d$clean_end_date[d$Community_id==42 & nchar(as.character(d$End_Date))==10] <- as.character(as.Date(d$End_Date[d$Community_id==42 & nchar(as.character(d$End_Date))==10], format="%m/%d/%Y"))
```

However, I am having a difficulty formatting dates in the format "11/31/2015" and "2014-02-29". I suspect this might be because R cannot distinguish between this format and formats of the same length like "2015/11/31" and "02-29-2014".

I would really appreciate help on this. I am fairly new to R, so would especially appreciate an answer that doesn't assume I speak R language fluently.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the guidance for asking R questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Comment: You might check out [`anytime::anydate`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) or [`lubridate::parse_date_time`](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate), which can handle multiple orders.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reflecting on the [**`guess_format`**](https://rdrr.io/cran/lubridate/man/guess_formats.html) function available in the aforementioned [`lubridate`](https://rdrr.io/cran/lubridate/) package.

## Examples

Quoting example from the official help linked above, given a set of dates:

```
x <- c('February 20th 1973',
       "february  14, 2004",
       "Sunday, May 1, 2000",
       "Sunday, May 1, 2000",
       "february  14, 04",
       'Feb 20th 73',
       "January 5 1999 at 7pm")
```

we can apply `guess_format` in the following manner:

```
require(lubridate)
as.Date(x = x, format = guess_formats(x, "mdy"))
```

### *Results*

This will match some of the dates:

```
>> as.Date(x = x, format = guess_formats(x, "mdy"))
 [1] "1973-02-20" "2004-02-14" "2000-05-01" "2000-05-01" "2004-02-14" "1973-02-20" NA           NA          
 [9] NA           "2000-05-01" NA           NA
```

You can explore different approaches to `guess_format`, on principle, it should result in a more parsimonious code than multiple combinations of grep